# text io wrapper error thing i very confused

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

k so i have code, and it works nicely. launcher.py runs all of this, so if things don't look like they are being executed, they are just from another location. i keep getting an error that looks like this:

`File "C:\<personal directories>\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} ' TypeError: Object of type TextIOWrapper is not JSON serializable`

i don't know why it does this. could I get some help? i may be missing something dum, but I have tried to find this error somewhere else.
code below:

````
    parent_dir = os.getcwd()
    created_dir = r"\Profiles"
    script_dir = parent_dir + created_dir
    profiles_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "Profiles.txt")
    try:
        with open(profiles_path, "r") as profile_file:
            profile_list = profile_file.read()
        print(profile_list)
    except IndexError:
        print("err")
    opening_question = input("please type the name of the profile you would like to enter. (case sensitive) \n \n $")

    parent_dir = os.getcwd()
    created_dir = r"\Profiles"
    script_dir = parent_dir + created_dir
    file_name = opening_question
    file_extention = ".json"
    file_dir = file_name + file_extention
    file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, file_dir)

    with open(profiles_path, 'r'):
        if opening_question in profile_list:
            with open(file_dir) as open_file:
                open_file = json.dumps(open_file, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
            print(open_file)
        else:
            print("Unknown choice", opening_question)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the content of file and pass the content to `json.dumps` not the file object itself

To read the content you may use file.read e.g. -

```
with open(profiles_path, 'r'):
        if opening_question in profile_list:
            with open(file_dir) as open_file:
                file_content = open_file.read()
                json_dump = json.dumps(file_content, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
            print(json_dump)
        else:
            print("Unknown choice", opening_question)
```